# How to create a Series of matrices in Python (with pandas and Gurobi)

Tags: python, pandas, gurobi

I'm doing a linear optimization in Gurobi and trying to make my decision variables in a Series of matrices, using this code:

```
schedule = pd.Series(index = Weekdays)
for day in Weekdays:
    schedule[day] = m.addVars(Blocks, Departments, vtype=GRB.BINARY)
```

But it keeps throwing an error "cannot set using a list-like indexer with a different length than the value." How do I get around this to make a list of matrices?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes across this, I figured out that the addVars method allows you to directly enter all three dimensions and uses a dictionary to reference. Therefore, you can simplify by writing:

```
schedule = m.addVars(Weekdays, Blocks, Departments, vtype=GRB.BINARY)
```

to reference, all you need to do is write:

```
schedule[weekday, block, department]
```